# PhpStorm: Failed loading xebug.so

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

When trying to debug a single PHP script, PhpStorm keeps complaining about xebug. I assume the correct name is xdebug, but I don't find a place where I have used xebug instead of xdebug including `/etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini` and `/etc/php.ini`. I think this is a PhpStorm bug.
Does anyone know what this is caused by and how can I fix it?

Detailed console error:

```
/usr/bin/php -dzend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xebug.so -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 myscript.phtml
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/xebug.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/xebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: *"I think this is a PhpStorm bug."*. No -- it's user error. Check your PHP Interpreter settings -- you must have provided wrong path to Xdebug extension.

Comment: @LazyOne Where could I have set interpreter settings other than php.ini or 15-xdebug.ini? I also did a find under `/etc`, but didn't find anything.

Comment: The first line is what is being called, and there's an error in `-dzend_extension` option. It must be somewhere in PhpStorm debugging configuration.

Comment: PHP Interpreter is set in PhpStorm, there it has separate field for Xdebug extension (so it can be loaded **only** when use use "Debug" button). You have provided wrong path (file name) there. This has nothing to do with php.ini settings.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP` -- check there (use search field -- it will narrow possible locations a lot).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Gotcha check it tomorrow morning